# Algoritmo para que no se repitan numeros aleatorios en un array (srand) en lenguaje C

Tags: array, c

Estoy haciendo un algoritmo y en una parte pide que los números generados automáticamente (Con un srand) no se repitan, pero no estaría sabiendo la forma de hacerlo, el código que tengo es:

```
for(i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    boletaGenerada[i] = rand() % 46;
    printf("%d\n", boletaGenerada[i]);
}
```

El código es mas largo ya que el algoritmo ha realizar es bastante extenso, pero creo que con esto ya bastaría.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Quiero decir que estuve viendo otro hilo en StackOverflow donde explicaban a otro usuario como hacer que no se repitan los números pero me pareció muy confuso, recurro a ustedes como último recurso, gracias

Comment: Podrias definir el time en NULL, para que cada vez que se ejecute el programa cambie su valor por medio de la fecha/hora del sistema.    srand (time(NULL));  A esta declaracion la debes hacer antes de rand()

Comment: @FrancoDreher eso no evita que se le pueda generar una secuencia en la que tenga repetidos. Con eso solo consigue que a cada ejecución la secuencia sea distinta.

Comment: Si hubo algo que no entendiste en ese hilo, mejor pedir las aclaraciones del caso ahi, si no solo van a repetir las respuestas que ya estaban..

Answer (score 1):

Puedes empezar con un array ordenado con los números 0 a 45, y generar un índice al azar entre 0 y el tamaño del array. Extraes el número que está en ese índice, y luego lo reemplazas por el último del array. La longitud del array será por tanto uno menos.

Repites el método tantas veces como necesites, (cada vez el array va menguando en 1, y ya no tiene el elemento que has sacado antes). Puedes seguir incluso hasta que la longitud del array llegue a 0, y en este último caso habrás obtenido una permutación aleatoria del array, lo cual sirve también como algoritmo para "barajar" los elementos del array.

Un ejemplo de código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_BOLAS 45
#define N_A_GENERAR 6

int main(void) {
  int bolas[NUM_BOLAS];             // Representa el "bombo" con las bolas
  int boletaGenerada[N_A_GENERAR];  // Estas serán las elegidas

  int i;
  int n;

  // Rellenar el "bombo" con las bolas ordenadas
  for (i=0;i<NUM_BOLAS;i++) bolas[i] = i;

  // "Sacar" N bolas del bombo
  for (i=0; i<N_A_GENERAR;i++) {
    n = rand() % (NUM_BOLAS+1-i);    // Elegir un índice dentro del array
    boletaGenerada[i] = bolas[n];    // Extraer la "bola" elegida
    bolas[n] = bolas[NUM_BOLAS-i-1]; // Reemplazar la "bola" elegida por la última del array
  }

  // Mostrar resultado
  for (i=0; i<N_A_GENERAR;i++) {
    printf("Num %d: %d\n", i, boletaGenerada[i]);
  }
}
```

Al ejecutarlo sale por ejemplo:

```
Num 0: 28
Num 1: 10
Num 2: 15
Num 3: 19
Num 4: 7
Num 5: 42
```

Comment: Probe el codigo, los numeros que genera siempre son los mismos, 41,42,43 y los otros 3 varian

Comment: Que te genere siempre los mismos números es normal, pues `rand()` es determinista (solo es pseudoaleatorio). Lo que es más sospechoso es que los tres primeros sean siempre 41, 42, 43, y más raro aún que los otros tres varíen. Mira, he hecho una demo en [repl.it](https://repl.it/join/pufyjjyt-abul4fia) y puede verse que si se reinicia la semilla aleatoria (usando `srand()`) los números varían.